# How to chain 2 Spring Mongo Reactive Save operations together?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-mongodb

I have a test case where I am trying to fire two save operations from two different services.  Both return Mono (I am not using the Spring Reactive Repository).

I want to do the following in order:

1. Save the profile
2. Create a Trait and update it using the profile
3. Transform/Save the trait (return the trait)

Individually they work.  When I try to chain the two of them together the 2nd operation does hangs depending on what I do (or just does not fire).

I assumed it was chained/subscribed to the first one?

```
Profile profile = new GenericProfile();

Object o = profileService.saveProfile(profile)
    .log()
    .flatMap(pp -> {
        TrackingTrait trait = new TrackingTrait(
            "cid",
            "tid",
            pp.getId(),
            null,
            "h",
            "p",
            null);
        return Mono
            .just(trait)
            .log();
    })
    .doOnNext(n -> log.debug("1 {}", n.getProfileId()))
    .flatMap(tt -> this.trackingService
        .track(tt)
        .log())
    .doOnNext(n -> log.debug("2 {}", n.getProfileId()))
    .block();
```

My output looks like this and it never finished to print the 2nd log statement (just spins).

```
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onNext(io.logicdrop.profiles.services.GenericProfile@1a01ffff)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | onNext(tid)
[DEBUG] i.l.analytics.AnalyticsPersistTest       : 1 5ad9ed16a29e0e2f82775a82
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | request(unbounded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy crap - it looks to be a bug in the way Spring/Mongo handles indexes combined with the Reactive stuff.  It was hanging on the second call trying to create the indexes.

I stumbled across this [Reactive mongo hangs with inheritance hierarchies defined in different gradle project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12875)

If I use this *workaround* and remove all the index annotations (@Index and @CompoundIndex), at least from the 2nd DAO, it worked.

Now, my log output looks like:

```
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onNext(io.logicdrop.profiles.services.GenericProfile@28519bfb)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | onNext(tid)
[DEBUG] i.l.analytics.AnalyticsPersistTest       : 1 5ad9f248a29e0e307f885e5e
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.Just.2                      : | onComplete()
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onComplete()
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | onNext(tid)
[DEBUG] i.l.analytics.AnalyticsPersistTest       : 2 5ad9f248a29e0e307f885e5e
[ INFO] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.3                   : | onComplete()
```